# MongoDB Query returns no results on NumberLong() field

Tags: mongodb, nosql-aggregation

I have around 11 million records with the following characteristics:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f29732595231d5fcb21faa"), 
    "PHONE" : NumberLong(593967848781), 
    "TRAFFIC" : NumberInt(0), 
    "ID_SUBPROD" : "PPA", 
    "TYPE" : "basic", 
    "MARCA" : "X", 
    "MODELO" : "G9"
}
```

I'm trying to check whether some phone numbers are duplicates.

I can perform queries and aggregations on every field EXCEPT "PHONE", for example an aggregation on "TYPE":

```
db.Phonebase.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$TYPE", count:{$sum:1}}})
```

Returns:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "feature phone", 
    "count" : NumberInt(2323827)
}
{ 
    "_id" : "basic", 
    "count" : NumberInt(2974583)
}
{ 
    "_id" : "smartphone", 
    "count" : NumberInt(3461723)
}
{ 
    "_id" : "", 
    "count" : NumberInt(2381208)
}
```

But an aggregation on "PHONE":

```
db.Phonebase.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$PHONE", count:{$sum:1}}})
```

Returns just the total count of phone numbers in the DB and not how many times each one is found:

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "count" : NumberInt(11141341)
}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your aggregation query seems correct. And this should have to do with `NumberLong`. From what I can speculate from the result you are pasting `"_id" : null` just tells me that the collection that you are running your query on does not have documents with `PHONE` field. Are you sure your documents have that field actually? Note that the field names are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes I'm sure there is a "PHONE" field, it would even be the primary key on a SQL database. That is why I tried to find duplicates. I can't even perform a find() operation